# Image and text position in list inline elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a web-page where I have a list of bands, and every image will be a small set picture of the band logo(or something). I am setting the style `inline` and I have tried `vertical-align` and `line-height` etc and nothing seems to work.

I am pretty sure I could accomplish this with `tables` but I have been told many times that is not the proper use of the `table`.

```
    <div id ="Content">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="IMG_3117.jpg"width="100" height="100"/>band name</li>
            <li><img src="IMG_3117.jpg"width="100" height="100"/>band name</li>
            <li><img src="IMG_3117.jpg"width="100" height="100"/>band name</li>
            <li><img src="IMG_3117.jpg"width="100" height="100"/>band name</li>
            <li><img src="IMG_3117.jpg"width="100" height="100"/>band name</li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the small amount of CSS I have

```
    #content li{display:inline;}
    img {
    max-height:100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    }

   #content ul{list-style-type: none;
    clear:left;
   }
```

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Get them all aligned vertically to the top? Bottom?

Comment: I am trying to get the text to line up below the image, however it is off to the right to the side of the image. I probably should have mentioned that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you're trying to do, try this:

```
#content li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 5px;
}

img {
    max-height:100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    display: block;
}

#content ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    clear:left;
}​
```

Have a look at it here: http://jsfiddle.net/zDhKQ/

Comment: yes! this is actually what I was trying to do!, im sorry for making so misunderstood :(

Comment: I knew I had a little bit of psychic in me ;)

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that you are looking for this:

```
#content ul li {
   float:left; 
}
```

otherwise you'd have to be a bit more specific on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want the align tag. Something like this:

```
<li><img src="IMG_3117.jpg" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" align="left">This is some text.
</li>
```

Will result in something that looks nice.